# Integrating Spring MVC with Angular

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I made a very simple application with Spring and Hibernate. It is a Employee repository. Now, I try to make frontend for that. I don't know anything about frameworks but I'm try to find the easier way to show my backend. So, I found that tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/ . Next, I made that 2 files with my data:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="demo">
    <head>
        <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="hello.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="Hello">
            <p>ID is {{employee.id}}</p>
            <p>The firstName is {{employee.firstName}}</p>
            <p>The lastName is {{employee.lastName}}</p>
            <p>The salary is {{employee.salary}}</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and hello.js:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="demo">
    <head>
        <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="hello.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="Hello">
            <p>ID is {{employee.id}}</p>
            <p>The firstName is {{employee.firstName}}</p>
            <p>The lastName is {{employee.lastName}}</p>
            <p>The salary is {{employee.salary}}</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have method which are returning "Employee" object:

```
@RequestMapping("/dawaj")
public Employee getEmploye() {
     return employeeRepository.findByFirstName("Jan");
}
```

I'm trying to integrate my result from localhost:8080/application/dawaj with index.html... Could you tell me why link: localhost:8080/application/dawaj is returning Json code and localhost:8080 is returning good index with data from getEmploye()? Can I integrate that method with index? I want that localhost:8080/application/dawaj is returning index.html with data from that method...

Project structure:
public | hello.js index.html **&&**
src    | main ...